How to get all my tokens from my contract
I need help getting all tokens in an array .
I’m making a geo location based game, where a user can mint an NFT and then pin it to the map. Once the NFT is pinned it gets added to my NFTS array
I want to call the getAllNFTs function and get the tokens that have been added to the NFTS array

Contracts ^5.0.0
pragma solidity ^0.8.20;

import "@openzeppelin/contracts/token/ERC721/ERC721.sol";
import "@openzeppelin/contracts/token/ERC721/extensions/ERC721Enumerable.sol";
import "@openzeppelin/contracts/token/ERC721/extensions/ERC721URIStorage.sol";
import "@openzeppelin/contracts/token/ERC721/extensions/ERC721Pausable.sol";
import "@openzeppelin/contracts/access/Ownable.sol";
import "@openzeppelin/contracts/token/ERC721/extensions/ERC721Burnable.sol";

contract GEONFTS is ERC721, ERC721Enumerable, ERC721URIStorage, ERC721Pausable, Ownable, ERC721Burnable {
   uint256 private _nextTokenId;

   struct Nft {
       uint256 id;
       string latitude;
       string longitude;
   }

   mapping(uint256 => Nft> public nfts;

   constructor(address initialOwner)
       ERC721("GEO NFTS", "GEO")
       Ownable(initialOwner)
   {}


Here’s how I’m minting and pinning the nfts
function safeMint(address to, string memory uri) public {
       uint256 tokenId = _nextTokenId++;
       _safeMint(to, tokenId);
       _setTokenURI(tokenId, uri);
   }

   function pinNFT(uint256 tokenId, string memory latitude, string memory longitude) public {
       require(ownerOf(tokenId) != address(0), "Token ID does not exist");
       nfts[tokenId] = Nft(tokenId, latitude, longitude);
   }


This is my get function that should return all the nfts in the array

function getAllNFTs() public view returns (Nft[] memory) {
       uint256 totalTokens = totalSupply();
       Nft[] memory allNfts = new Nft[](totalTokens);
       for (uint256 i = 0; i < totalTokens; i++) {
           uint256 tokenId = tokenByIndex(i);
           allNfts[i] = nfts[tokenId];
       }
       return allNfts;
   }

My error when calling it on the front end:
call revert exception [ See: https://links.ethers.org/v5-errors-CALL_EXCEPTION ] (method="getAllNFTs()", data="0x", errorArgs=null, errorName=null, errorSignature=null, reason=null, 

Frontend code:

const abi = [
        "function getAllNfts() view returns (tuple(uint256 id, string latitude, string longitude)[])",
        "function tokenURI(uint256 tokenId) view returns (string memory)"
      ];

      const provider = new ethers.providers.Web3Provider(window.ethereum);
      const contract = new ethers.Contract(contractAddress, abi, provider);
      const allNfts = await contract.getAllNFTs();


Any help is appreciated thank you

Are you able to call getAllNFTs() function in your smart contract i.e., when calling it from Remix or any block explorer ?

The issue is that _nextTokenId starts at 0 and increments to 1 on the first mint, but your loop in getAllNFTs starts at 0, which doesn't exist. Start _nextTokenId at 1 and increment it after minting to avoid accessing token ID 0. This way, you only work with valid token IDs in getAllNFTs.
